# Filtrar valor especifico al momento de ser agregado, Firebase DB

Tags: javascript, nodejs, firebase, nosql, firebase-messaging

Mi problema radica en que estoy intentando obtener una respuesta automática de un dato especifico si es agregado en **Firebase**, pero el inconveniente es que no es una ruta especifica que puedo colocar para simplemente obtener el valor agregado con `child_added` puesto a que tengo varios nodos dentro del mismo nodo padre, esto quiere decir que en lugar de tener una estructura estática como `db.ref("chats/unicoChat/messages/")` lo que tengo es algo como esto `db.ref("chats/"+currentChat+"/messages/)` (siendo `currentChat` una variable que puedo seleccionar a través de x método en mi aplicación) por lo que al momento de utilizarlo en mi aplicación podría seleccionar el chat a través de la id del mismo que obtengo con una snapshot, con una variable y todo perfecto...

Pero el problema esta en que quiero recibir una notificación cuando llegue un mensaje nuevo, por lo que necesito que Firebase me mande una respuesta del mensaje cuando la ruta especifica sea modificada, y así obtener una snapshot del mismo.

He intentado ordenar por hijo para saltarme el especificar que chat necesito, quedando de la siguiente manera `ref("chats").orderByChild("messages")` pero esto me manda todos los chats que contengan la ruta `messages/` si cualquiera es modificada, por lo que no me sirve a menos que haya una manera de filtrar el nodo que tuvo la modificación y que yo desconozca, si la hay, perfectamente podría ser una respuesta valida!

La estructura de mi base de datos es la siguiente:

```
chats
 . LQTYGaRNvdE1PNkyrd3
 .  . chatId: LQTYGaRNvdE1PNkyrd3
 .  . messages
 .  .  . -LQTYHrHLMqxZIkybn9G
 .  .  .   . Date: Sun Nov 04 2018
 .  .  .   . Time: 7:00:00
 .  .  .   . Message: Hola como estas?
 .  .  .   . peerName: denyn_crawford
 .  .  . XCantidadDeMensajes
 .  .  .  .
 .  .  .  .
 .  . peers
 .  .  . 1: denyn_crawford
 .  .  . 2: otra_persona
 . XCantidadDeChats
 .  .
 .  .
```

**Explicación de la estructura**

Dentro de chats tengo un nodo con un id único para cada chat y dentro coloco los metadatos del chat en cuestion, tal como los "peers" que son los usuarios que participan en la conversación, el id del mismo, y los mensajes.

Dentro de cada chat tengo mi ruta `messages/` donde se almacenan los mensajes del mismo y cada mensaje tiene un id único también, donde guardo los metadatos necesarios tales como la hora y fecha, así como el mensaje en cuestión.

**Conclusión**

Como ven los chats tienen un id único por lo que no puedo crear una variable fija que escuche un ruta especifica para recibir la notificación, entonces para resumir:

> ¿Que debo hacer para que Firebase me envié un callback o snapshot con la información especifica del ultimo nodo **modificado**/**agregado**/**removido** si cuento con una ruta dinamica para llamarlo?

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A quien pueda interesar**

La respuesta es simple, ya pude solucionarlo por mi propia cuenta.

**Explicación**:

En realidad el inconveniente se da porque cuando buscas la ruta que requieres ya sea que no conozcas el nodo especifico donde se almacena tu nodo agregado o al contrario, como en los ejemplos de arriba, al utilizar el evento `child_added` este solo escucha cuando un nodo hijo es agregado (***como "child_added" quiere decir***), lo que sucede en mi referencia es que estoy escuchando solo cuando un mensaje llega, pero por mi manera de agregar los datos, los datos hijos que en realidad se están agregando son los datos del mensaje en cuestión, por lo que al utilizar `child_added` no me devuelve ningún dato nuevo. Por otro lado si escuchamos con el evento `value` este me devuelve toda la data con cualquier cambio/agregado/removido que exista, y no solo eso, sino que me devuelve los datos generales de la ruta, cosa que no pasa con `child_added` ya que este me devuelve solo la data del hijo especifico agregado en cuestión.

**Para evitar confusiones**:

> **CITA**: "*He intentado ordenar por hijo para saltarme el especificar que chat necesito, quedando de la siguiente manera ref("chats").orderByChild("messages") pero esto me manda todos los chats que contengan la ruta messages/ si cualquiera es modificada...*"

Esto sucede como dije porque cuando ordeno por hijo, solo esta obteniendo todos los datos que coincidan con en nodo hijo solicitado (en este caso "messages") entonces al combinarlo con el `value` cuando ocurre algo en mi base de datos que afecte a un hijo con la ruta "messages/" el evento me devuelve todos los datos de la ruta general si cualquier dato es cambiado, mas **no significa** que utilizar `.orderByChild()` no sea la manera correcta.

**Solución**:

Para solucionar el problema solo tenemos que utilizar el evento `child_changed` que hace lo mismo que `child_added` pero solo si cualquier dato de la ruta es cambiado, devolviendo el dato especifico del nodo cambiado, que en este caso es el cuerpo completo del mensaje, que esta siendo cambiado al agregarle los nodos hijos (en este caso, los metadatos del mensaje).

**Ejemplo**:

```
db.ref("chats").orderByChild("messages").on("child_changed", function(snap){
  foo...
});
```

**Conclusión breve**:

Siempre hay que tener en cuenta de que manera se agregan los datos, y también como se requieren.

**Fuentes**:

[Detecta eventos secundarios - Firebase database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_child_events)

[Cómo ordenar y filtrar datos - Firebase database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data)